# Systemjs transpiler complains but typescript compiler worked fine

Tags: typescript, systemjs

So I've been using tsc for my project for now but 11 sec compiling is really long and I wanted to see how fast can transpiling be and the whole experience.

After some tinkering I managed to get the transpiling working but I'm getting a few errors which I can see are connected but I don't know how to fix them.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

for lines:

```
services_1.customSetTimeout(function () self.watchForMessage(self), self.displayTimeoutInterval);

self.timeout = setTimeout(function () self.getTrack(self), delta * 1000);

return System.import(path).then(function (c) c[name]);

static isUserInjector() {
  return function (next, prev) core_1.Injector.resolveAndCreate([AuthService, core_1.provide(services_1.HttpAdvanced, { useClass: services_1.HttpAdvanced })]).get(AuthService).isUser();
}
```

and:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this
```

for line:

```
setTimeout(function () this.getItems(this), dt * 60 * 1000);
```

Now I can see that the issue is that setTimeout is not in any library but a native js function, and I have not explicitly mentioned Systemjs anywhere as a library.

How would I add these 2 easily so that noone complains? I get that adding a library should not be a problem but `setTimeout` kinda buggs me because I tried declaring it and it didn't help

Would it be possible to make systemjs give more information about the syntax errors?

Comment: (unrelated) `self.doSomething(self)` seems counter intuitive to me, you are passing some value as `this` and also as the first parameter to the function. Why is that necessary?

Comment: setTimeout overrides `this` of the function so I could not access other class functions

Comment: My point is that if you call `self.doSomething()`, `self` will be available as `this` inside doSomething

Comment: Yeah in javascript but typescript does not allow it